# How to increase the amount of time to consider input complete, in android voice recognition?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

In android voice recognition, Can any one know how to increase the amount of time that it should take after we stop hearing speech to consider the input possibly complete. I need to prevent the endpointer cutting off during very short mid-speech pauses while voice recognition. If anyone knows the solution, please give reply. Any response would be appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two parameters are relevant and they control the amount of silence the recognizer needs to hear before stopping.

EXTRA_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS
or
EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS

They both seem to control the same thing and which ever is lower is the one it uses.

For example, if complete_silence = 20000 and possibly = 10000 then the recognizer will stop after it hears 10000 milliseconds of silence.

Comment: i configured this but it still works only for 10 seconds even though I configured for 30 seconds.

Answer (score 5):

Hi Im also having this problem, but I found something,

here's my code

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()   
    {   

        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);   

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);   
//        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000000);   
//        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000000);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 20000000);

        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "XXXXXXX");   

        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);   
    }
```

in google API I found the 3 extra to change the time issue, but none of them seems to work, u can also try to test them.

Comment: I also tested. Those three extras seem to do nothing. The documentation suggests that it's possible for them to be ignored by the engine. It's unfortunate.

Comment: make it to be : intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(5000)); Then it will work. :)

Comment: I tried all options and none of them seem to work at all.

Answer (score 3):

```
String EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS   The amount of time that it should take after we stop hearing speech to consider the input complete.
 String EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS    The minimum length of an utterance.
 String EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS  The amount of time that it should take after we stop hearing speech to consider the input possibly complete.
```

These parameters stopped working for Jelly Bean devices. They still work for ICS devices and below.

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works for me. 5 sec. waiting for you to start talking

```
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 50000000);
```