# Set the minimum timeout for input voice with recognizer speech

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I'm working with the recognizer speech (without the default popup, but with the manual way), so far all is working well except one thing. I tried to change the minimum timeout for the input voice, because it's too short by default, so I would like to set the timeout to 5 seconds. I tried with many ways but nothing seems to work. I tried with and without dictation mode and partials results, the result is the same. Here the code for the intent:

```
Intent mRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra("android.speech.extra.DICTATION_MODE", true);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, this.getPackageName());
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, false);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
mRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 5000); // tried with new Long(5000) but same...
```

I don't know if it's a bug known or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase the amount of time to consider input complete, in android voice recognition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5388957/how-to-increase-the-amount-of-time-to-consider-input-complete-in-android-voice)

Comment: Yes, I already saw this post and tried with those 3 params but same result unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried a longer number? Like 20000000

Comment: I did, nothing changes

Comment: THe SpeechRecognizer is a 3rd party app.  It may well just not honor that field in the request, there's no way to force it to.

Comment: It's too bad because the delay is very short sometimes. I don't understand while Google says that we must set this extra to change it...

Comment: I see in the docs that [depending on the recognizer implementation, these values may have no effect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html#EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS).

Comment: You're right... Like the RMS callback which isn't always called too.

Comment: hi @ejay have you resolved the issue or any workaround for this

Comment: hi @Rahul Khurana, unfortunately not :/

Comment: still no workarounds?